# SearchDelegate in Flutter: The method 'where' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to do a search in my application and I'm using this **SearchDelegate** for that. Previously, when I used a provider, everything worked, but I had to make serious changes in the code and now this algorithm below is responsible for finding routes. I am trying to put `RouteWithStops` in  **SearchDelegate**, and after that to use FutureBuilder inside  `Widget buildSuggestions`. So the code is like this:

The algorithm for searching routes with stops with dart models:

```
Future<List<RouteWithStops>> getMarshrutWithStops(int ttId) async {
    if (routesbyTransportType.isEmpty) {
      await fetchTransportWithRoutes();
    }
    List<Routes> routes = routesbyTransportType[ttId].routes;
    List<ScheduleVariants> variants = [];

    variants.addAll(await api.fetchSchedule());

    List<RouteWithStops> routesWithStops = [];

    for (Routes route in routes) {
      final routeWithStops = RouteWithStops();

      routesWithStops.add(routeWithStops);
      routeWithStops.route = route;

      routeWithStops.variant =
          variants.where((variant) => variant.mrId == route.mrId).first;
    }
    return routesWithStops;
  }

  Future<RouteWithStops> fetchStopsInfo(routeWithStops) async {
    List<RaceCard> cards = [];
    List<StopList> stops = [];
    cards.addAll(await api.fetchRaceCard(routeWithStops.variant.mvId));
    stops.addAll(await api.fetchStops());
    print(cards);
    List<StopList> currentRouteStops = [];

    cards.forEach((card) {
      stops.forEach((stop) {
        if (card.stId == stop.stId) {
          currentRouteStops.add(stop);
        }
      });
    });
    routeWithStops.stop = currentRouteStops;
    return routeWithStops;
  }

}
```

the models:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class RouteWithStops {
  @HiveField(0)
  Routes route;
  @HiveField(1)
  List<StopList> stop;
  @HiveField(2)
  List<RaceCard> cards;
  @HiveField(3)
  ScheduleVariants variant;
  @HiveField(4)
  Transport transport;


}
```

The SearchDelegate which I want to use to search in a list of routes, the single route I want:

```
class SearchBar extends SearchDelegate<RouteWithStops> {
  final int ttId;
  final RouteWithStops routeWithStops;
  TransportService service = getIt<TransportService>();

  SearchBar({this.ttId, this.routeWithStops});

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () {
            query = '';
          })
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
          progress: transitionAnimation,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {


    return FutureBuilder(
        future: service.getMarshrutWithStops(ttId),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          List<RouteWithStops> routes = snapshot.data;
          List<RouteWithStops> routes = [];
          List<RouteWithStops> recentRoutes = [];
          final suggestion = query.isEmpty
              ? recentRoutes
              : routes
              .where((element) => element.route.mrTitle.startsWith(query))
              .toList();
          print(routes?.toString());
          return (routes == null)
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: suggestion.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          text: suggestion[index]
                              .route
                              .mrTitle
                              .substring(0, query.length),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: service.getMarshrutWithStops(ttId),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          List<RouteWithStops> routes = snapshot.data;
          List<RouteWithStops> recentRoutes = [];
          final suggestion = query.isEmpty
              ? recentRoutes
              : routes
                  .where((element) => element.route.mrTitle.startsWith(query))
                  .toList();
          print(routes?.toString());
          return (routes == null)
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: suggestion.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          text: suggestion[index]
                              .route
                              .mrTitle
                              .substring(0, query.length),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
        });
  }
}
```

When i am trying to serach an item in items I get the progress indicator and after I trying to type one letter my app crushes and I got this error:

```
The method 'where' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: where(Closure: (RouteWithStops) => bool)
```

I understand that this error is pretty straightforward and it sayas that something is null inside that algorithm, but I use this algo in the whole app and everything works fine without any errors. But may be I think wrongly in using SearchDelegate. Can somebody, please, help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
future: service.getMarshrutWithStops(ttId),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          List<RouteWithStops> routes = snapshot.data;
          List<RouteWithStops> recentRoutes = [];
          final suggestion = query.isEmpty
              ? recentRoutes
              : routes
                  .where((element) => element.route.mrTitle.startsWith(query))
                  .toList();
          print(routes?.toString());
```

Your `snapshot.data` is `null`. You have a FutureBuilder and *no* check on the status of the future at all. It might have failed or still be processed.

Also, don't call your Future generating method in your `build` method. Use a variable. Your build method can be called many times and you don't want to generate a new future every time that happens.